# Casting child to a different child Java

Tags: java, casting

I am trying to cast a child to a sibling in Java (though I'm not sure if this is allowed). Basically what is written below:

```
public interface BaseInterface {
    public int a = 5;
}

public class ClassA implements BaseInterface {
    public int a = 3;
}

public class ClassB implements BaseInterface {}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BaseInterface a = new ClassA();
    ClassB b = (ClassB) a;
}
```

I keep getting a ClassCastException. I am trying to copy all member variables from the BaseInterface object a to b. Can someone provide a solution on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Two words: Copy constructor.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. Instead, you should give `ClassA` and `ClassB` [copy constructors](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=12) taking a `BaseInterface`:

```
public class ClassB implements BaseInterface {

    public ClassB(BaseInterface other) {
        //copy state from other instance
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BaseInterface a = new ClassA();
    ClassB b = new ClassB(a);
}
```

Of course this means you're copying to a new object instead of converting, but it's the only option if you want to go from a `ClassA` to a `ClassB`.

Answer (score 0):

A `ClassA` is not a `ClassB`, so of course this is not allowed. Even if you suppress all warnings/errors and get the code to compile, at runtime the cast will cause a [`ClassCastException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassCastException.html).

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment if you're not suggesting what to fix?

Comment: Copy constructor is a way to achieve what the OP is asking for?

Comment: @JuanMendes you're entirely right. My goal was to explain _why_ this approach isn't possible.

Comment: I suppose... However OP's code wouldn't compile as is anyways.

Comment: @Juan Mendes: given the vague description of what the OP actually expected by cross class casting, there's really nothing that can be recommended yet.

Answer (score -1):

```
public interface BaseInterface {
    public int getA();
}

public class ClassA implements BaseInterface {
    private final int a;

    public ClassA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
}

public class ClassB implements BaseInterface {
    private final int a;

    public ClassB(BaseInterface baseInterface) {
        this.a = baseInterface.getA();
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BaseInterface a = new ClassA(5);
    ClassB b = new ClassB(a);
}
```

Will do what you want. As others noted, casting will always give a `ClassCastException`.